# Android drawables : Is there any way to somehow link the int IDs to the R drawable IDs?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I have 718 drawables in the `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`and `drawable-xhdpi` folders, whose names are 1.png, 2.png... to 718.png. (They are actually Pokémon sprites)

So, depending on the Pokémon, I want to load one of them to show it. However, I cannot use the number to directly identify the R drawable ID.

Is there any way (besides of a 718-case switch or a `Hashmap<Integer,Integer>`) to somehow link the int IDs to the R drawable IDs?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
String sprite = "drawable/"+number; 
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(sprite, null, getPackageName());
```

The `drawable` is the folder where the image is in. The `number` is the number of the image you want. e.g. 1.png

Comment: What was the difference from my answer and this? . The second argument type is optional. You can also set the resource type

Answer (score 0):

Name the `Drawables` as image_1.png ..to.. image_718.png.

Using `getIdentifier` you can get the drawable resource Id like this.

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("image_1", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `TypedArray` to define the images in an array resource. then you can load the resource and get the resources as offsets. It will be significantly faster than using getIdentifier().  Note that I added a 0.png drawable, so the array indices would match your numeric values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array name="icons">
    <item>@drawable/0</item>
    <item>@drawable/1</item>
    <item>@drawable/2</item>
    <item>@drawable/3</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

Then in your code:

```
 Resources res = getResources();
 TypedArray sprites = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
 Drawable drawable = sprites.getDrawable(1);
```

Here's the resources link which gives the background: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html