# Unable to Set Layout Background from Drawable - Android / Java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-drawable

I'm attempting to set a layout background from an image I have stored on a server - however so far I have been unsuccessful.

I found this example:

[setBackgroundResource from numeric string causes Fatal Error - Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620851/setbackgroundresource-from-numeric-string-causes-fatal-error-android-java)

However for some strange reason - the layoutbackground is never changed:

```
        // Set LayoutBackground from URL 
        LinearLayout linearLayout0 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.download);
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                background,
                "drawable", getPackageName());
        linearLayout0.setBackgroundResource(resId);
```

I've debugged the issue and for some reason the value of `resId = 0` and I'm unsure why (I believe it should be something along the lines of drawable.)

### Values (after debugging):

```
drawable = http://1xx.1xx.x.1xx/bgs/bg_1287.jpg
resId = 0 
linearLayout0 = android.widget.LinearLayout{42903680 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0a008e app:id/download}
```

Comment: why that approach? download it and set it via inputstream

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to load your `drawable` from URL before trying to set it as a background.